# backup job fails due to assigned(H) drive being deactivated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, backup

i am running server 2003 and its primary function is running SQL backups i have the H drive assigned to receive all the SQL backup jobs done over weekend but for some strange reason on some occasional mondays the jobs fail b/c the assigned drive H is deactivated in this case i simply go into disk management and reactivate the disk(H) and the H drive shows up again and the drive is assigned to its correct letter and place. everything is fine afterward reactivation but i would like to know why is this happening? and is it possible to minimize or prevent this all together ?

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: the 2003 wserver is designated to daily backups and weekly backups with sql server 2005(actual product installed) the H drive is designated to receive all the backups but sometimes the H drive deactivates for some odd reason and when i reactivate the H drive run the backup jobs it works fine. any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like this should be posted on ServerFault.com instead of here